# Microsoft Office Hyperlink Issues

Tags: vba, hyperlink, powerpoint

When creating a hyperlink in powerpoint or word 2010 to take the user to our website, the link changes from what I put in powerpoint to include a "?target=" tag after the domain name followed by the remainder of the link. This then for some reason forces the user to log in again before accessing the website (a secured site) even if they are already logged in. However, if the link I provided is pasted in the browser as I thought powerpoint would basically do, everything works as intended and the user is brought to the desired location within our site if logged in.

I ended up getting it to work via a method with vba, but I was wondering if anyone could explain why this might be happening. I'm not entirely sure if this is something on our end or something to do with powerpoint or maybe both. Thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you type in vs. what PPT shows? And where does PPT show this target tag? That is, where do you see that it added a tag? If you edit a hyperlink, there is a Target Frame button that allows you to determine the target argument of the anchor, but that shouldn't be adding a ? parameter to the URL. Edit a hyperlink, click on Target Frame and see if it's set to something other than 'none'.

Comment: I give it:
http://www.virtualhighschool.com/d2l/lms/content/viewer/main_frame.d2l?ou=61089&tId=473649

And it gives me:
https://www.virtualhighschool.com/?target=%2fd2l%2flms%2fcontent%2fviewer%2fmain_frame.d2l%3fou%3d61089%26tId%3d473649

Where is this Target Frame button? I can't seem to find it under Edit Hyperlink. I'm using ppt 2010.

Comment: I guess there's no Text Frame button in PPT. There is in Word and Excel, so that's odd. When I type that URL into a slide, it doesn't make it a hyperlink. If I put www at the front, it creates the hyperlink but doesn't append ?target to the url - it's all normal. If I copy/paste the link location it does not append. If I Ctrl+K and paste the link location, not appending. Can you walk through the specific steps for creating the link and where you see that it has appended a target?

Comment: Oh it only appends the target when you follow the link. At least for me it does.

Comment: OK, we're getting out of my area of expertise, but... I can confirm that it adds target when you click it. For me, it also adds target when I paste it. That's because I'm not logged in. The target is added by the website, not Office. It puts that there so it can send you where you wanted to go after you log in. The root of the problem (I think) is that Office doesn't respect your default browser's cookies/cache and doesn't even respect Internet Explorer's. I have a crazy experiment for you if you're up for it.

Comment: Go into Excel and choose Data - From Web. Navigate to the site and log in through Excel's New Web Query dialog. Grab anything on that page and make a web query out of it to complete the process.  Now go click that link in PPT and see if it includes the target. Once you're logged in (via Excel) Office's private web browser will recognize it and take you right to the page. Maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely due to the behavior https://github.com/spilliton/fix_microsoft_links is designed to fix.

Basically this is because when Office products try to open a link, they open it internally, follow any redirects, and analyse the resulting document to see if it can be opened with an Office application. When the link needs to be opened with a browser, they forward on the final url (result of a redirect) to the browser, which in your case is the login page. When opened in the browser, it notices we are already logged in and redirects to wherever your application goes in that case, possibly the login page